# Regex to exclude dollar sign and dot in number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using ParseHub to scrape some tables with currency numbers. Some of the values are:

- $1.000,00
- $800,64
- $100,00

I'm struggling to find a javascript regex that extracts these numbers, in a single group, in this format:

- 1000,00
- 800,64
- 100,00

So basically I need to ignore dollar symbol and dot in thousands.

The regex `([-0-9\/|,]+)` works well for everything, except `$1.000,00` where it returns only `1`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [\$(\[\d,.\]+)](https://regex101.com/r/g0mUlM/1)

Comment: Thanks dawg, but this returns 1.000,00 instead of 1000,00

Comment: The replacement at that point is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `JavaScript` version:

```js
let numbers = ['$1.000,00', '$800,64', '$100,00'];
numbers.forEach(function(number) {
    number = number.replace(/[$.]+/g, '');
    console.log(number);
});
```